# runnable JAR file issue

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I created a (supposedly) runnable JAR file on the command-line containing 3 java files, where `JarLab.java` is the class to run. All three were compiled and each class's source file and class file was placed into the jar file `"lab4.jar"` (for a total of 6 files, not including the manifest). All three classes are part of package `csc143.jar`, so the top of each `.java` file reads:

```
package csc143.jar;
```

After doing this, I entered:

```
java -jar lab4.jar
```

but this error arose:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class csc143.jar.JarLab
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Did you also include a manifest file?

Comment: please tell command you used for creating the jar

Comment: @user2581779 : copy the contents of manifest to question.

Comment: The JAR file does include a **correct** manifest, since the JVM "knows" it should look for `csc143.jar.JarLab`. Are the classes packaged put in the right directory inside the JAR?

Comment: This is one of the most common questions on this site.  Search around for similar questions or find a tutorial on line.  It will take forever for us to figure out your problem by prying info out of you one step at a time.  If you _really_ want to get some help around here, provide **way** more details and describe all the steps you're using to build the jar in great detail.  So far you've told us almost nothing.  What commands are you running to build the jar?  What OS?  Are you using ant?  Are you using Maven?  Do you expect us to guess all of these things? Let's see the contents of the jar..

Comment: @ @user2581779  : see note from mthmulders. Most likely your jar structure does not match class FQN.  Please see  if it has "csc143/jar/JarLab.class"